# Best approach to change mobile background image and adding its class

Tags: plugins, customization, theme-development, block-editor, core

- I have extended `core/group` block to add different background image when its being viewed on smaller view port.
- I would like to know what will be best approach to add class name here which I did in my code or something other also doubt is if I choose to change image with CSS then for all groups in single page background image on mobile device will be same and if I choose to do it with JS then on page refresh only it will get triggered.

```js
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { MediaUpload, MediaUploadCheck } = wp.blockEditor;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { __ } = wp.i18n;

/**
 * Adds the mobileBackgroundImage attribute to the group block settings.
 *
 * @param {Object} settings - The block settings.
 * @return {Object} - The updated block settings.
 */
function addMobileBackgroundImageAttribute( settings ) {
    if ( 'core/group' !== settings.name ) {
        return settings; // Return settings even if the block name doesn't match
    }

    settings.attributes = {
        ...settings.attributes,
        mobileBackgroundImage: {
            type: 'string',
            default: '',
        },
    };

    return settings;
}

addFilter( 'blocks.registerBlockType', 'addMobileBackgroundImageAttribute', addMobileBackgroundImageAttribute );

/**
 * Higher Order Component to add class name and inspector controls to core/group block.
 * This HOC adds a mobile background image control to the core/group block.
 *
 * @param {Function} BlockEdit - Original component.
 * @return {Function} - New component.
 */
const withClassNameAndInspectorControls = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        const { name, attributes, setAttributes } = props;

        if ( 'core/group' !== name ) {
            return <BlockEdit { ...props } />;
        }

        const oldClassList = attributes.className ? attributes.className : '';
        const removeClass = oldClassList?.replace( 'has-mobile-background-image', '' );

        return (
            <>
                <BlockEdit { ...props } />
                <InspectorControls group="styles">
                    <PanelBody title={ __( 'Mobile Background Image', 'features' ) }>
                        <MediaUploadCheck>
                            <MediaUpload
                                onSelect={ ( media ) => {
                                    setAttributes( { mobileBackgroundImage: media.url, className: oldClassList + ' has-mobile-background-image' } );
                                } }
                                type="image"
                                value={ attributes.mobileBackgroundImage }
                                render={ ( { open } ) => (
                                    <>
                                        <button className="button button-large" onClick={ open }>
                                            { attributes.mobileBackgroundImage ? __( 'Change Image', 'features' ) : __( 'Select Image', 'features' ) }
                                        </button>
                                        { attributes.mobileBackgroundImage && (
                                            <>
                                                <img src={ attributes.mobileBackgroundImage } alt={ __( 'Mobile Background', 'features' ) } className="mobile-background-image" style={ { marginTop: '10px', maxWidth: '100%' } } />
                                                <button
                                                    className="button button-large"
                                                    onClick={ () => {
                                                        setAttributes( { mobileBackgroundImage: '', className: removeClass } );
                                                    } }
                                                >
                                                    { __( 'Remove Image', 'features' ) }
                                                </button>
                                            </>
                                        ) }
                                    </>
                                ) }
                            />
                        </MediaUploadCheck>
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
            </>
        );
    };
}, 'withClassNameAndInspectorControls' );

addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'addMobileBackgroundImageControl', withClassNameAndInspectorControls );

/**
 * Higher Order Component to add class name to core/group block in the editor.
 *
 * @param {Function} BlockListBlock - Original component.
 * @return {Function} - New component.
 */
const addEditorClass = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        const { wrapperProps, name, attributes } = props;

        if ( ! [ 'core/group' ].includes( name ) ) {
            return <BlockListBlock { ...props } wrapperProps={ wrapperProps } />;
        }

        const newWrapperProps = {
            ...wrapperProps,
            ...( attributes.mobileBackgroundImage &&
            {
                'data-mobile-background-image': attributes.mobileBackgroundImage,
            } ),
        };

        return <BlockListBlock { ...props } wrapperProps={ newWrapperProps } />;
    };
}, 'withTooltip' );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockListBlock', 'features', addEditorClass );

/**
 * Adds the mobileBackgroundImage attribute to the group block settings.
 *
 * @param {Object} settings - The block settings.
 * @return {Object} - The updated block settings.
 */
addFilter( 'blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps', 'addClassNameToGroupBlockFrontend', ( extraProps, blockType, attributes ) => {
    if ( attributes?.mobileBackgroundImage ) {
        return {
            ...extraProps,
            'data-mobile-background-image': attributes.mobileBackgroundImage,
        };
    }
    return extraProps;
} );
```

```php
add_filter( 'render_block_core/group', array( $this, 'extend_core_group_block' ), 10, 3 );

public function extend_core_group_block( $block_content, $block, $instance ) {
        // Add JavaScript to dynamically set background images.


        $image_path = '';
        if(isset($instance->parsed_block['attrs']['mobileBackgroundImage'])){
            $image_path = esc_url( $instance->parsed_block['attrs']['mobileBackgroundImage'] );
        }

        if(isset($image_path) && $image_path !== ''){
        ?>
        
        <style>
            @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
                .wp-block-group.has-mobile-background-image {
                    background-image: url(<?php echo $image_path; ?>) !important;
                    background-size: cover;
                }
            }
        </style>
        <?php
        }

        wp_add_inline_script(
            'jquery',
            '
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                if ($(window).width() < 768) {
                    $(".wp-block-group.has-mobile-background-image").each(function() {
                        var backgroundImageURL = $(this).data("mobile-background-image");
                        $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + backgroundImageURL + ")");
                        $(this).css("background-size", "cover");
                    });
                }
            });
        '
        );

        return $block_content;
    }
```

- latest update on code

```php
public function extend_core_group_block( $block_content, $block, $instance ) {

        $image_path = '';
        if(isset($instance->parsed_block['attrs']['mobileBackgroundImage'])){
            $image_path = ( $instance->parsed_block['attrs']['mobileBackgroundImage'] );
            var_dump($image_path);
            wp_add_inline_style(
                'up1512001-2024-styles',
                '@media (max-width: 768px){
                    .wp-block-group.has-mobile-background-image[data-mobile-background-image="' . $image_path . '"] {
                        background-image: url(' . esc_url($image_path) . ') !important;
                    }
                }'
            );
        }

        return $block_content;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you have a call to `wp_add_inline_script` with JS to remove/show the CSS when there's a CSS media query that does that already. Is this not already handled by the cover block? A cover block with a style variant that hid its background image when the page is wider than 768px would do this without any filters or JS to mess with the frontend

Comment: I need specific behaviour for core/group block and I have showed two approaches one with `media` query and another with `wp_add_inline_script` but doing this with `media` query will apply same image to all group block present in page and doing with `inline script` will only trigger on page refresh.
So how should I handle this?

Comment: The current media query outputs the same rule but with different attributes repeatedly, if it used the ID it would be more specific, and wouldn't put background images on all group blocks. Likewise if you inserted the background image with an inline style you could flip the media query and use it to set all group blocks above a certain size to have no background image. It also sounds like this is an X Y problem for an unnamed issue that requires you to have this specific behaviour for the group block. If you can explain why you need that behaviour it can help avoid Q's and give better answers

Comment: I don't think by default, the `core/group` block has given any IDs I guess need to set it as an attribute and then update the image accordingly.
 
I am working on a project in which there are two different images are set as background images (one for desktop and one for mobile) the designer doesn't want to change it and the manager doesn't want to use the visibility plugin so this is the whole story of extending `core/group` block.

Comment: by default no, but you do have an attribute and a value that you can write a selector for, `.wp-block-group.has-mobile-background-image[mobile-background-image="...."]`, the attribute you already have is enough to pick out just that element

Comment: public function extend_core_group_block( $block_content, $block, $instance ) {
  if(isset($instance->parsed_block['attrs']['mobileBackgroundImage'])){
   $image_path = esc_url( $instance->parsed_block['attrs']['mobileBackgroundImage'] );
   var_dump($image_path);
   wp_add_inline_style(
    'up1512001-2024-styles',
    '@media (max-width: 768px){
     .wp-block-group.has-mobile-background-image[data-mobile-background-image="' . $image_path . '"] {
      background-image: url(' . $image_path . ') !important;
     }
    }'
   );
  }

  return $block_content;
 }

Comment: In this way, I am adding image but still not reflecting and getting the valid `var_dump()` URL of the image.

Comment: can you edit that into your question? It's difficult to read in comment form. Also Use `esc_url` as late as possible, not at the point of assignment, otherwise double escaping and modification can occur unintentionally. Also when you say getting the valid vardump URL do you mean it is showing the expected URL or it is not? I don't think `wp_add_inline_style` makes that much sense when you're filtering the output of a block, it's easier to append the style tag and possibly more performant. I'd also prefer `empty` over `isset`

Comment: I updated the question and yes vardump is showing the URL that I want to set as the background image. I used `isset()` because all blocks of the page don't have mobile image attribute.

Comment: true, but if the attribute is empty you wouldn't want to perform actions either, have you confirmed the CSS rules are being added? And checked they match the elements? It would be much easier to check with `$block_content .= '<style>....`, likewise `var_dump` outputs immediatley which could lead to the value appearing in the wrong place, especially with nested blocks

Comment: Thanks `Tom J Nowell`, got it working by your mentioned way and updated the same in question.

Comment: can you post that as an answer rather than an edit? Then we can mark it as correct and I can upvote it! Don't forget to explain your steps so it isn't just a code block

Comment: updated is as answer and thank you for your help `Tom J Nowell`.

Comment: Hey `Tom J Nowell`, I was wondering why `wp_add_inline_style()` isn't working here. Any ideas?

Comment: As per the docs `Styles will only be added if the stylesheet is already in the queue.`, though in this case I don't believe it's an appropriate use to call it inside a block renderer like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As I am extending core/group block to add option for setting different image for smaller displays I used `render_block_core/group` filter to add style tag.
- I am already adding `data-mobile-background-image` to each group for its mobile view background image so there is no need for updating it through ID as suggested by `Tom J Nowell`.

**Final Code for setting image using only CSS**

```php
add_filter( 'render_block_core/group', array( $this, 'extend_core_group_block' ), 10, 3 );

public function extend_core_group_block( $block_content, $block, $instance ) {

        if ( isset( $instance->parsed_block['attrs']['mobileBackgroundImage'] ) ) {
            $image_path     = ( $instance->parsed_block['attrs']['mobileBackgroundImage'] );
            $block_content .= '
                <style>
                    @media (max-width: 768px){
                        .wp-block-group.has-mobile-background-image[data-mobile-background-image="' . esc_attr( $image_path ) . '"] {
                            background-image: url(' . esc_url( $image_path ) . ') !important;
                        }
                    }
                </style>
            ';
        }

        return $block_content;
    }
```